# Insert data into .accdb (ms access) failed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm doing insert username and password into database in vb.net but it gives this error:

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F25WK.png)

can someone take a look what cause it?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Amin\source\repos\Nando's\Nando's\user.accdb"

    connstring = pro
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
    myconnection.Open()
    command = "insert into user ([USERNAME],[PASSWORD]) values ('" & USERNAMETextBox.Text & "','" & PASSWORDTextBox.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    myconnection.Close()

    MsgBox("Record added", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

End Sub

Comment: In `PASSWORDTextBOX.Text` enter: `a'); DROP TABLE user;--` (seriously don't) use parameters, `Using` statements to ensure disposing does happen and finally never store passwords like that.

Comment: Well, it's quite clear reading the error message, there is something wrong with the insert statement.  Use parameters rather than string concatenations, you will find doing it properly will make your problem disappear

Comment: And before following Codexer's advise, please backup your db

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("USERNAME", CType(USERNAMETextBox.Text, String)))` parameters also give the same error @Hursey

Comment: Not using parameters will open up the flood gates, you don't want that. My point is someone can craft a handy query in an input that could be executed and by using parameters helps prevent that.

Comment: What values are you trying to insert?  Do they contain reserved characters?  And USERNAMETextBox.Text is already a string, should need to CType it

Comment: I need to insert username and password for new user into user table. I've followed many tutorial and it is all kinda same at gives me error.

Comment: Thank you @Codexer. I already change it into parameters but it gives the same error. 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

Comment: Try insert into user (USERNAME,PASSWORD) without the square brackets.  After that, what is the values of username and password?

Answer (score 0):

I change from this:

```
command = "insert into user ([USERNAME],[PASSWORD]) values ('" & USERNAMETextBox.Text & "','" & PASSWORDTextBox.Text & "')"
```

to this:

```
command = "insert into [user] ([USERNAME],[PASSWORD]) values ('" & USERNAMETextBox.Text & "','" & PASSWORDTextBox.Text & "')"
```

I just put a bracket at `user` and it is solved.
The bad thing is I was going back and forth between tutorial for days but neither of them solve it because the error was on the table name but it is finally solved. Thank you to Hursey for mentioning reserved words.

Comment: You may have solved your immediate problem but please learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and other problems. Also, **PLEASE** don't store passwords as plain text.